# View is not Rendering after using formatter function in UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, formatter

I am using formatter function for date which is of type String. I want to display it in `yyyy/mm/dd` format after validation, say if value is `"Unavailable"` it should display Blank[View is rendering].

if not I should display it in `YYYY/MM/DD` format. so I sliced the Time value and in debugger it is returning the value which I am expecting but the view is not rendering.

Other formatter functions are working. The Problem came after using Slice function.

**View**

```
<Text text="{ path:'FORMULATIONDATE', formatter:'.getFormulation'}" wrapping="false" />
```

**Controller**

```
getFormulation: function(FORMULATIONDATE) {
  debugger;
  FORMULATIONDATE = FORMULATIONDATE.slice(0, 10);
  return (FORMULATIONDATE === "TimeUnavailable") ? null : FORMULATIONDATE;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code? View, formatter and an example of the data you are binding (before formatting)

Comment: in View:<Text text="{path:'FORMULATIONDATE', formatter:'.getFormulation'}" wrapping="false"/>    controller:    getFormulation: function(FORMULATIONDATE){
   debugger;
FORMULATIONDATE = FORMULATIONDATE.slice(0, 10);

   return FORMULATIONDATE === "TimeUnavailable" ?  null: FORMULATIONDATE;}   Date:"09/05/2017 04:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

Considering `FORMULATIONDATE` is a date object from the service.

**Solution 1: Using Model type**

```
<Text text="{path: 'FORMULATIONDATE', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', 
      formatOptions: {pattern:'yyyy/mm/dd', UTC: true}}" /> <!--update your format -->
```

**Solution 2: Using formatter**

*XML view*

```
<Text text="{path: 'FORMULATIONDATE', formatter: 'formatter.formatDate'}" />
```

*Formatter.js*

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat");
formatter = {
    formatDate: function(FORMULATIONDATE) {
        var dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern : "dd.MM.YYYY"});//this is the default format
        if (FORMULATIONDATE == null) {  
            dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern : "dd.MM.YYYY"});//update your format           
        } 
        var sFormatDate = dateFormat.format(FORMULATIONDATE);   
        return sFormatDate;
    }
}
```

Note: If `FORMULATIONDATE` is not the date object then use `new Date(FORMULATIONDATE)`